# ng-click is removed by ngsanitize

Tags: angularjs

I am getting setting some html text in my `$scope` variable which also contains `ng-click` attribute so that it on click of a link it will call angular controller function.

```
$scope.message = "dum messge<a data-ng-click='loadCalenderData()'>retry</a>";

//view
<div ng-bind-html="message"></div>
```

I tried both `data-ng-click` and `ng-click` but no luck.

Comment: You need to use the `$compile` service for that, ng-bind-html is for non-angular html only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not $compiled. When you bind-html, that doesn't tell Angular to search through that HTML and compile directives within it. You'll need a custom directive for this.

Check this link     https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/312mbg/ngclick_on_element_inserted_using_ngbindhtml_not/

Answer (score 1):

That's ng-sanitise's job, to prevent any unauthorized markup or script being rendered on the page.

This is a simpler mechanism that separates your error message from the markup/functionality:

```
//view
<div ng-bind-html="message">
<a data-ng-click='loadCalenderData()' ng-show="message">retry</a>
```

If you want it to depend on something else, just use a different scope variable